# Find time complexity of this recursive function

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

This algorithm is a bit nonsense because I reduced it to the basic scheme.

Basically, it takes a string as input, scan this string and create a new string that does not contain the first letter of the old string.
Is that a O(n^2)? If you can justify the answer. Thank you.

```
recursiveProc(String myString){
    if(myString.length() >= 1){
        char firstLetter = myString.charAt(0);
        String newString = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++){
            if(myString.charAt(i) != firstLetter){
                newString = newString + myString.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        recursiveProc(newString);
    }}
```

Comment: You can take the worst-case scenario of all different characters, so for a string of length _n_ a new string of length _n - 1_ is created.

Comment: Why do you need `recursiveProc(newString);` this recursive call at all?

Comment: @JoopEggen Yes, so I have n recursive call and in each one a n-1 loop. So at the end? This is my problem

Comment: @vivek_23 in this case I could not use it but I need to do the analysis as it is

Comment: @cieco1109 Eran said it all O(N²) assuming no string operations adding to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually worse than `O(N^2)`. Looks like `O(N^3)`.

Each recursive call will reduce the input `String` by at least one character, so there would be at most `N` recursive calls (in the worst case there would be exactly `N` recursive calls, each reducing the input `String` by exactly one character).

However, your loop takes `O(N^2)`, since it has `O(N)` iterations, and each iteration creates a new `String` whose length is not a constant.

Suppose you have the String "0123456789"

The first recursive call will remove the '0' character by creating the following `String`s:

```
"1"
"12"
"123"
"1234"
"12345"
"123456"
"1234567"
"12345678"
"123456789"
```

This would take `O(N^2)` time. And that's just the first recursive call.

You could improve it by using a `StringBuilder` instead of `String` concatenation to create the new `String`.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(myString.length()-1);
    for(int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++){
        if(myString.charAt(i) != firstLetter){
            sb.append(myString.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    recursiveProc(sb.toString());
```

In that case the loop would take `O(N)` (since each iteration of the loop does constant work) and the entire recursion would take `O(N^2)`.